# Cannot push viewcontroller from appdelegate

Tags: ios, uiactionsheet, pushviewcontroller, appdelegate

1. In my window base application I need to navigate to editorview from my appdelegate when i click on the second item of my tabbarcontroller it will shows an actionsheet with three option.
2. actionsheet works fine, it will shows an actionsheet if you choose the second item from tabbar.
3. But i need to push to the other view when i choose the first option of my action sheet
4. i declare my actionsheet in appdelegate.
5. i already implement the actionsheetdelegate

   - (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex

the method is trigerred and it can shows if i do nslog. but it cannot push to the viewcontroller that i want..
here's my code:

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
    {
        if (buttonIndex == 0)
        {
            DetailViewController *v2 = [[DetailViewController alloc] init];

            NSLog(@"PUSH TRIGER");

            [self.window.rootViewController.navigationController pushViewController:v2 animated:YES];
        }
    }
```

NOTE: I already embed my tabbarcontroller and navigation controller in my storyboard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do like this

What did you assign VC for `UITabBarController` ? I bet `UIViewController`? Try assign `UINavigationController` instead of `UIViewController`

synthesize `UINavigationController *navController`;

```
self.navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
SomeViewController *viewController = [[SomeViewController alloc]  initWithNibName:@"SomeViewController" bundle:nil];
self.navController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:viewController];

UITabBarController *tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
[tabBarController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
self.navController, nil]];
```

Then on your actionsheet

```
[self.navController pushViewController:v2 animated:YES];
```

**EDIT for storyboard**

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
   self.navController = (UINavigationController*) [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyNavController"];
```

Hope that helps

Comment: but i already embed my tabbarcontroller and navigation in storyboard, that's why i didn't declare my tabbarcontroller again

Comment: i'think you were right, maybe my storyboard design was wrong, i already put the segue identifier and the viewcontroller identifier and it still didn't work, could you please check my storyboard, i want to push to the view controller in the red circle here's the pic: http://i46.tinypic.com/5jz704.png

Comment: the picture is too small , can i see the bigger one?

Answer (score 10):

It is full of bad answer related to this issue.

I hope mine fits your requirements.

1.- Inside of

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary*)userInfo
```

// 1.- First: instantiate the navigationController. Normally the rootviewcontroller

```
 UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
```

// 2.- Second: Instantiate Storyboard 
// It might be tagged MainStoryBoard. Be careful if you've changed it

```
UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle: nil];
```

// 3.- Third instantiate the VC you want to navigate
// In my particular case it is called IniciarSliderViewController . Don't forget to import it in the appdelegate. Also pay attention to tagged correctly. In my case MenuSlider

```
IniciarSliderViewController *controller = (IniciarSliderViewController*)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"MenuSlider"];
```

//4.- And last one, you can now push as you usually do in the VC

```
[navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

Don't hesitate to ask if you still have problems

Comment: Works but the Navigation is lost

Answer (score -2):

instead of this     self.window.rootViewController.navigationController

use UINavigationController object